# ¿Why does Spring Security config produce a cvc-complex-type.2.4.c on Websphere Application Server?

Tags: xml, spring-security, configuration, websphere

I've been struggling with this problem for a couple of weeks. I have some legacy code that I recently migrated to Spring 5 from 4. The code runs fine on localhost but when uploaded to WebSphere Application Server it crashes severely.

The error looks like this:

> **Error Page Exception**
>
> **SRVE0260E: The server cannot use the error page specified for your application to handle the Original Exception printed below.**
>
> **Original Exception:**
>
> **Error Message:** javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [springSecurityFilterChain]: could not be initialized
>
> **Error Code:** 500
>
> **Target Servlet:** main
>
> **Error Stack:**
>
> org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 8 in XML document from file [/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/******/installedApps/******/******.ear/******.war/WEB-INF/classes/spring/spring-security.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but **no declaration can be found for element 'http'.**
>
> at stack stack stack and so on...

I have been on to this for a week and I think I have tried with all the usual suspects.

- I use the same version (5.2.0) of all Spring modules in my Maven dependencies.
- I do have spring-security-config as a dependency.
- I have checked the packaged application. My `.ear` includes my `.war` that in turn includes `spring-security-config.jar` on its `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

Strangely, I have tried removing spring-security-config.jar from my ear and the error is still the same. I then started to suspect the spring-beans.xsd definition. I have written a simple script to output all packaged files on my first-level dependencies (no transitive deps) but only one `spring-beans.xsd` and one `spring-security.xsd` are there.

Since the problem only exists on WebSphere Application Server, I tried configuring the classloader to use local classes first, just in case some server-side version of spring was messing with my software. This did not affect the result in any way whatsoever.

Here is what my `spring-security.xml` config file looks like:

```xml
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <b:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:b="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
             http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

        <http security="none" pattern="/services/**"/>
        <http security="none" pattern="/css/**"/>
        <http security="none" pattern="/fonts/**"/>
        <http security="none" pattern="/images/**"/>
        <http security="none" pattern="/js/**"/>
        <http security="none" pattern="/error/**"/>
        <http security="none" pattern="/api/**"/>

        <http>
            <intercept-url pattern="/validationCheck" access="permitAll"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/validationCheckStatus/**" access="permitAll"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/ping" access="permitAll"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/login.htm" access="permitAll" requires-channel="https"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/login-error.htm" access="permitAll" requires-channel="https"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/logout" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="https"/>
            <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" requires-channel="https"/>

            <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/"/>
            <form-login login-page="/login.htm" authentication-failure-url="/login-error.htm"
                                 login-processing-url="/login.htm" default-target-url="/index.htm"
                                 always-use-default-target="true"/>

            <port-mappings>
                <!-- Default ports -->
                <port-mapping http="80" https="443"/>
                <!-- Websphere default ports -->
                <port-mapping http="9080" https="9443"/>
                <!-- Websphere DES default ports -->
                <port-mapping http="9082" https="9445"/>
                <!-- Tomcat default ports -->
                <port-mapping http="8080" https="8443"/>
                <!-- Jetty custom ports -->
                <port-mapping http="7777" https="7443"/>
            </port-mappings>

        </http>

        <authentication-manager>
            <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider"/>
        </authentication-manager>

    </b:beans>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Spring Security version 5.2.0, the XSD schema translation described in `spring-security-config.jar/META-INF/spring.schemas` now reads like this:

```
https\://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-5.2.xsd
https\://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-5.2.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-5.2.xsd
http\://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-5.1.xsd=org/springframework/security/config/spring-security-5.1.xsd
...
```

The new schema and the versionless pointer now are addressed only through HTTPS.

The solution to my problem was to set all my schema locations to resolve like this:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security https://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd
```

with the second part pointing to an `https` protocol URL.

This is also described [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/7560) and has been solved in subsequent Spring Security versions but it took me a week to figure out this subtlety.

Comment: I work with spring-security 5.8.1. Although the mappings are present in the spring.schemas file in the jar, nothing helped me; At the end, only indicating the version in the schemaLocation URL directly solved the problem: https://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-5.8.xsd. And both, using http or https, is working. BTW: I had the problem in eclipse (2022-06), and at runtime (of unit tests) in gitlab.